# execute multiple command in vb together

Tags: ms-access, vb6

i am working on a vb project . in this i need to save some record to one table and update some records in another table in one event or click .. i am doing like this .

```
       Conn.Execute "insert into DailyStock(serial,category,model,datee,opnstock,supply,phystk,totalsale,ssale,nsale,totalstock)values(" & txtserial.Text & ",'" & CboCategory.Text & "','" & CboModel.Text & "','" & DTPicker1 & "'," & txtopnstock.Text & "," & txtsupply.Text & "," & txtphystk.Text & "," & txttsale.Text & "," & txtssale.Text & "," & txtnsale.Text & "," & txtstock.Text & ") ; update Menu set phystk=" & txtstock & " where ItemName='" & CboModel & "'"
       MsgBox ("Data  Saved Successfully")
```

but it giving error as "character found after sql statement" .. i am not getting where i go wrong .. please help me

Comment: Let's hear it for [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only run one statement at a time in MS Access. Everything after the ";" is a character found after sql statement.

```
Conn.Execute "insert into DailyStock(serial,category,model,datee,"_
 & "opnstock,supply,phystk,totalsale,ssale,nsale,totalstock)values(" _
 & txtserial.Text & ",'" & CboCategory.Text & "','" _
 & CboModel.Text & "','" & DTPicker1 & "'," & txtopnstock.Text _
 & "," & txtsupply.Text & "," & txtphystk.Text & "," & txttsale.Text & "," _
 & txtssale.Text & "," & txtnsale.Text & "," & txtstock.Text & ") "

Conn.Execute "update Menu set phystk=" & txtstock _
 & " where ItemName='" & CboModel & "'"
```

Comment: when i use the code like this it gives an error as no value given for one or more required parameter .. can you tell me why this showing

Comment: Check your insert string and make sure it is good sql, that is, print it to the immediate window or such like. I am a bit suspicious of `& "','" & DTPicker1 & "'," &`, date fields are delimited with hash (#), not single quote (')

Comment: Most of all, make sure that you have spelled all the field names propery, for example, is `datee`, `date_e` or even `dateend`?

Comment: But far more importantly, that you sanitize any text that goes into the query (or parameterised queries)

Comment: Parameter queries don't require the same sort of "sanitizing" that cobbled-up literal queries do.  However you still want to validate data most of the time before storing it.

Comment: Yeah, I was advocating parameterised over all the the whole query string thing.